# Class templates and constructors

Tags: templates, constructor, d

Templates are a great to add some features to a class, but there is a problem with the constructors: it only works when the template ctor and the class (passed as parameter) ctor have the default form. ([DPaste tester](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/7f2ede3e))

```
module main;

class cInternalMandatoryClass{};
class cImplementSomeStuffs(T): T 
if((is(T==class)/* & (HaveADefaultCtor!T) */))
{
    private:
    cInternalMandatoryClass fObj;
    public: 
    void Something1(){}
    this(){fObj = new cInternalMandatoryClass;}
    ~this(){delete fObj;}
}

class cSource1
{
    int fA;
    this(){fA = 8;}
}
class cSource2
{
    int fA;
    this(){}
    this(int a){fA = a;}
}

class cSourceWithSomeStuffs1: cImplementSomeStuffs!cSource1
{
    this()
    {
        assert(fObj !is null); // check cImplementSomeStuffs ctor
        assert(fA == 8); // check cSource1 ctor
    }
}

class cSourceWithSomeStuffs2: cImplementSomeStuffs!cSource2
{
    this(int a)
    {
        // need to call cSource2 ctor
        assert(fObj !is null); // check cImplementSomeStuffs ctor
        assert(fA == 9); // check cSource2 ctor, fails
    }
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    auto Foo = new cSourceWithSomeStuffs1();
    delete Foo;
    auto Bar = new cSourceWithSomeStuffs2(9);
    delete Bar;
}
```

Is it possible to call cSource2 ctor in cSourceWithSomeStuffs2 ?
If not, is there a trait to test that a class have a default constructor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a chain of `super` calls, forwarding the constructor arguments:

In `cImplementSomeStuffs`:

```
this(A ...)(A args) // formerly this()
{
    super(args);
    // etc ...
```

In `cSourceWithSomeStuffs2`:

```
this(int a) // could be this(A ...)(args), too
{
    super(a);
    // etc ...
```

Comment: Ok, but the sources class must have at least an empty this(), otherwise the compiler produces an error. The presence of a default ctor must be tested.

Answer (score 0):

When class is inherited like this `class C : Base {}` or templatized like this `class C (Base) : Base {}`, then the default constructors is called on the `Base` class, if not done otherwise.

to call other that default constructor include **super** call in the derived constructor like:

`class C : Base { super(myArguemnts); your code }`

`class C (Base) : Base { super(myArguemnts); your code }` this can get trickier as yo don't know what type of Base will be, so you might not know what types of arguments, if any, it will accept

you can forward arbitrary augments like this if needed

`this (Args...) (int a, int b, Args args) { super (args); }` You can pas any number of arguments to Args.